# A pandas groupby operation on a categorical index that respects order

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I want to groupby and aggregate to go from the first cell to the second cell in the below image (aggregate method is mean).

[image: Fig 1]

Comment: Please don't post images. Instead, paste everything as text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) with `Series.cumsum`:

```
In [662]: df = pd.DataFrame(index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a'], data=[1,2,3,4,5], columns=['val'])

In [634]: x = df.reset_index()

In [653]: df['new'] = (x['index'] != x['index'].shift()).cumsum().tolist()

In [659]: df.groupby('new').transform('mean').drop_duplicates()
Out[659]: 
   val
a  1.0
b  2.0
c  3.5
a  5.0
```